# How to turn toggle button off automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be toggle button automatically off and whatever I will select that product should be off. And when click on then it should be show that product.

**HTML**

```
<div class="heading" id="seamless" style="display: none;">
   <center>PayPal now accepted! Make a sale and we'll email you to claim your funds. Easy!Your email: admin@example.com</center>
</div>
```

**Toggle Button**

```
<div id="normal-toggle-button">
   <input name="open" value="1" type="checkbox" onchange="checkshowhidereverse(this.status, '#seamless');checkshowhidereverse(this.status, '#setup');" checked="checked" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //* toggle buttons
   toggle_buttons.init();
});
```

**Javascript function**

```
//* toggle buttons
toggle_buttons = {
    init: function () {
        $('#normal-toggle-button').toggleButtons();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if i understood it well?

**Initially DIV is hidden, checkbox unechecked ? if yes how about this**

http://jsfiddle.net/8sCw8/

```
<div class="heading" id="seamless" style="display: none;">
<center>PayPal now accepted! Make a sale and we'll email you to claim your funds. Easy!Your email: admin@example.com</center>
</div>

<div id="normal-toggle-button">
<input id="checkBox" name="open" value="1" type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#checkBox').click(function() {
 if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
     $("#seamless").show();
 } else {
     $("#seamless").hide();
 }
});
```